# Dismiss a ui dropdown in semantic

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, semantics

I need to dismiss a ui dropdown while hovering over it. Now, the ui drop down is just visible and never shows or hides when tapped or clicked.

Here are the snippets:

```
<div ng-show="user" class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
    <span class="text">Reg</span>
    <i  class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu transition visible">
      <a class="item" href="/xyz">
        Schools
      </a>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <a class="item" href="/xyz2">
       Admissions
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

UI drop down is initialized like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/components/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.ui.dropdown')
.dropdown();
</script>
```

What changes are needed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the css class `simple` for hover.

```
<div ng-show="user" class="ui pointing simple dropdown link item">
    <span class="text">Reg</span>
    <i  class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu transition visible">
      <a class="item" href="/xyz">
        Schools
      </a>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <a class="item" href="/xyz2">
       Admissions
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And in JS file ,you need to initialize like below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I want the dropdown to be dismissed when Reg is clicked and reappear when clicked again

Comment: with the above answer, the dropdown is not stable. before u select the child dropdown it dismissions

Comment: You need to open the dropdown on click of `Reg` right ?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css

Comment: @rocket please check the updated answer., this is working in my end.

Comment: On my end it’s working fine , can you post your code in codeplex ??